# Exported tag vs Intent filter

Tags: android

If you have a component in your manifest which uses exported="False" but then has an intent filter description, is this component exported or not? Can it be used by other apps?

Answer (score 1):

> is this component exported or not?

It will not be exported.

However, that also means that you do not need the `<intent-filter>`. I cannot think of any scenario where you want to have a non-exported component with an `<intent-filter>`.

> Can it be used by other apps?

Since it is not exported, third-party apps cannot work with the component independently. There are ways to allow third-party apps to have limited access to non-exported components (e.g., `PendingIntent`, `grantUriPermissions`), but that always involves your app granting conditional temporary access.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this was fixed after you reported it to Google then? :) Do you know with which version Google released the fix?

Comment: @Alice: Sorry, but I am not certain what you are referring to.

Comment: That's my bad. I had commented a link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892721/activity-exported-false-listed-in-activity-chooser, but then I realized that neither the question nor your answer there explicitly states that the component is not actually exported, and I deleted my comment, since you answered here.

Comment: @Alice: Yes, this appears to be different now. [The last comment on that issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29535#c8) happens to be from me, and indicates that the flawed behavior was changed in Android 4.2.

Comment: out of curiosity: [if I understood correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892721/activity-exported-false-listed-in-activity-chooser) at the beginning [before Android 4.2] `intent-filter`s existence was making a component exported even if it was declared as `exported="false"`. Then from Android 4.2 in case of controversy it looks from this answer that `exported="false"` became predominant on the `intent-filter`s. And [now](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported) for Activities in such situation "system throws an ActivityNotFoundException". Right?

Comment: @Antonino: The only change that I can think of in the 4.x timeframe related to components being exported is that a `<provider>` used to be exported by default and then became not-exported by default. I do not recall any change related to how `<intent-filter>` affects the exported status. And I have not experimented with a non-exported activity with an `<intent-filter>` recently to see how it behaves with respect to the activity chooser, etc.

Comment: thanks Mark, I will give a look into it as soon as possible! keep up the good work you do and thanks for your huge and extremely knowledgeable Android activity!